# excel vba :why doesn't this nested for loop do 1 to multiple comparison?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following nexted for loop

```
'searches matches in Col C against B
For Row = 2 to totalrows Step 1

    'MsgBox "cell :" & Cells(Row, 2).Value
    For c = 2 To totalrows Step 1
        MsgBox " cell b :" & Cells(c, 2) & " cell C:" & Cells(rows, 3).Value
        If Cells(c, 3).Value = Cells(Row, 2).Value Then
            'change b color to orange = found
            With Cells(c, 2).Interior
                .ColorIndex = 4
                .Pattern = xlSolid
            End With

        End If

    Next c
Next Row
```

right now it compares 
b1 = c1 
b2= c2 
b3 = c3 
instead of 
b1 = c1
b1 = c2 
b1 = c3
b2 = c1
b2 = c2 
...

am i missing something?

Comment: In msgbox, when you get the value of cell b you missed the .value, And when you get the value of cell c you wrote cells(rows, 3), which is wrong, should be cells(row,3)

Answer (score 1):

In msgbox, when you get the value of cell b you missed the .value, And when you get the value of cell c you wrote cells(rows, 3), which is wrong, should be cells(row,3).
Probably (since other's posts code are very similar to yours) it works fine but the message boxes it shows are wrong because of this line of code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub a()
totalrows = 3
'searches matches in Col C against B
For Row = 2 To 2 + totalrows Step 1

    'MsgBox "cell :" & Cells(Row, 2).Value
    For c = 2 To 2 + totalrows Step 1
        MsgBox " cell B :" & Cells(c, 2).Value & " cell C:" & Cells(Row, 3).Value
        If Cells(c, 3).Value = Cells(Row, 2).Value Then
            'change b color to GREEN = found
            With Cells(c, 2).Interior
                .ColorIndex = 4
                .Pattern = xlSolid
            End With

        End If

    Next c
Next Row
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Maybe I should mention that what was in the msgbox and what was compared was not the same and I changed this.

I work with debug.print and open the immediate window that helps. I have this in my sheet

```
a1  b1  c1  d1
a2  b2  c2  d2
a3  b3  c3  d3
a4  b4  c4  d4
```

This is the code

```
Sub mysub()

totalrows = 4

'searches matches in Col C against B
For Row = 1 To totalrows Step 1

    Debug.Print "row = " & Row
    'MsgBox "cell :" & Cells(Row, 2).Value
    For c = 1 To totalrows Step 1
        'MsgBox " cell b :" & Cells(c, 2) & " cell C:" & Cells(Row, 3).Value
        Debug.Print " cell b :" & Cells(Row, 2).Value & " cell C:" & Cells(c, 3).Value
        If Cells(Row, 2).Value = Cells(c, 3).Value Then
            'change b color to orange = found
            With Cells(c, 2).Interior
                .ColorIndex = 4
                .Pattern = xlSolid
            End With

        End If

    Next c
Next Row
End Sub
```

This is the result

```
row = 1
 cell b :b1 cell C:c1
 cell b :b1 cell C:c2
 cell b :b1 cell C:c3
 cell b :b1 cell C:c4
row = 2
 cell b :b2 cell C:c1
 cell b :b2 cell C:c2
 cell b :b2 cell C:c3
 cell b :b2 cell C:c4
row = 3
 cell b :b3 cell C:c1
 cell b :b3 cell C:c2
 cell b :b3 cell C:c3
 cell b :b3 cell C:c4
row = 4
 cell b :b4 cell C:c1
 cell b :b4 cell C:c2
 cell b :b4 cell C:c3
 cell b :b4 cell C:c4
```